# Low resolution for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view with a few collection view cells in it like the picture below. It seems to have really bad quality graphics compared to the rest of the UI.

The screenshot was taken on a real iOS device with retina display to show you.

Any help?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You need to provide some code showing how these elements are laid out. Off the top of my head though, this happens when you have elements positioned and sized using decimals (fractions of a point). The compiler will not complain but the elements will end up being split between multiple pixels and appearing blurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dima was right, thanks.

I had code attached to the CALayer for a shadow effect which made it low resolution:

```
cell.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
cell.layer.borderWidth = 7.0f;
cell.layer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25f;
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
cell.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:cell.bounds].CGPath;
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

Comment: Specifically this line           cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;